# net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.setMessageEmitter(net.sf.saxon.event.Receiver) not available when using Camel XSLT component

Tags: apache-camel

I get the following error when trying to use the Camel XSLT component:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.setMessageEmitter(net.sf.saxon.event.Receiver)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to include Saxon-HE 9.4 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.4.0.7). Versions above this don't appear to have the methods that Camel 2.14.1 needs.